# Not able to enter full text in editbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to enter a text into an editbox however sometimes it enters only half of the text (it fails to enter first few Characters)

i.e. for below code `enterFirstName("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901")` only enters `30` or so charcter rather than `41`

```
By firstNameEditbox = By.id("firstName");

public void enterFirstName(String firstName){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(identifier));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    element.sendKeys(firstName);
    findElementWithWait(firstNameEditbox).
}
```

> **url:** https://mpower.tvo.org/educators/#/signup/
>
> **WebDriver Version:** 3.5.2
>
> **Browser:** Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
>
> **Chrome Driver Version:** 2.26.436382

Any idea why it's happening or how to resolve this?

Comment: Most likely a side effect of all the listeners assigned to the field. The same listener is assigned 3 times for the `keydown` event. You could try to call `sendKeys` on each character. Another way would be to simulate a paste with a script injection: `var elm=arguments[0], txt=arguments[1]; elm.focus(); elm.value=txt; elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: how did you come to know about listeners, if you could explain it would help me in future.

Comment: Inspect an element, all the listeners are in the panel on the right in the "Event Listeners" tab.

Comment: @FlorentB. Thanks. The field has hell lot of event listners and so many are duplicate. for now I have applied to solution to enter string by it's characters. it's not the perfect solution but it's working for now

Answer (score 0):

To input long text, I normally use js to improve performance and this use:

```
public boolean setValue(String text) {
    logger.info(String.format("<%s(%s) set value '%s'", el.getTagName(), el.getText(), text));
    try {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webElementFinder.getDriver();
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];",
                waitForElementVisible(config.getBrowserElementFinderTimeout()), text);
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        logger.warn(
                String.format("<%s(%s) Element not visible within timeout period", el.getTagName(), el.getText()));
        return false;
    }
}
```